# Copy multiple files from 1 location to other in cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, copy-paste

```
copy C:\Integration\integration-batch.jar integration-post-processor.jar integration-translator.jar E:\MyFolder
```

I want to copy my files "integration-batch.jar, integration-post-processor.jar, integration-translator.jar" to E:\MyFolder the above command not working for me.

Comment: http://jpsoft.com/help/copy.htm

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the folder where the files are located (ie. C:\Integration), then:

**In Windows:**

for %I in (integration-batch.jar integration-post-processor.jar integration-translator.jar) do copy %I e:\MyFolder

**In Linux/Mac OS:**

cp integration-batch.jar integration-post-processor.jar integration-translator.jar E:\MyFolder

It will automatically use the last name in your command is the destination directory.

Comment: for %I in (integration-batch.jar integration-post-processor.jar integration-translator.jar) do copy %I E:\MyFolder

It created a file name MyFolder in my E: drive

Comment: Sorry, forgot the backslash on the end of the destination file. Try this: for %I in (integration-batch.jar integration-post-processor.jar integration-translator.jar) do copy %I e:\MyFolder\

Comment: `e:\MyFolder` has to exist first.  Or you create it in the batch file.